# AWS ElasticBeanstalk Django display images

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i uploaded my Media directory which contains my Images but i cant access it to display
my images. My images are correctly being uploaded when i send them, but i cant view them in the page

Im utilizing ElasticBeanstalk and RDS - Mysql

I only configured my RDS everything else like EC2, S3 are automattically configured by ElasticBeanstalk

commands I used on eb:

> ```
> eb init
> eb create
> eb deploy
> ```

static-files.config:

> ```
>  option_settings:
>      aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
>          /static: static
>          /media: media
> ```

django.config:

> ```
>  option_settings:
>      aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
>          WSGIPath: store.wsgi:application
> ```

01_packages.config:

> ```
>  packages:
>      yum:
>          python3-devel: []
>          mariadb-devel: []
> ```

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images/%Y/%m/%d')
```

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

my html:

```
                <a href="{{product.get_absolute_url}}">
                    <img class="default-img" src="{{product.image.url}}}" alt="550x750">

                </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following configuration which worked for me.

**settings.py**

```
DEBUG = False
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
```

Now run `python manage.py collectstatic`

In root urls.py make following configuration

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve 

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    ...
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), 
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}), 
]
```

You can refer [Github](https://github.com/cyborg7898/poll-app) for better idea. Thank you